# Why my Game is trying to connect to External server

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Hi noticed that my game is trying to connect to "https://cdp.cloud.unity3d.com/" i don't have analytics active and i have pro version of unity 2017.1 any one knows if is possible to disable that? I;m running on WebGL build

[image: Chrome console]

Comment: Go to Edit-->Preferences-->General then make sure that "Disable Editor analytics" is disabled.  Unity collects data from builds. That data is why developers have important information to improve their app such as [this](https://hwstats.unity3d.com/index.html).